# Tradução do nome de serviços do Windows

Tags: windows, services

Estou usando o Windows em Português no meu trabalho. Preciso seguir um tutorial em inglês para permitir que o firewall do windows volte a funcionar.

Não encontro o serviço "base filtering engine service" na lista de serviços em Portugues.Alguém sabe o nome equivalente?

Comment: Veja aqui: [Tradução nomes serviços windows En-PT](http://mymemory.translated.net/en/English/Portuguese/windows-service).

Comment: Em sua defesa, não consegui achar essa lista ao procurar em português, Já em inglês a busca foi fácil (windows service names, portuguese translation).

Answer (score 0):

O nome deste serviço é **Mecanismo de Filtragem Básica**. O nome curto é **BFE**.

Fiquei supreso de não conseguir achar uma lista que compare os nomes inglês/português.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Estou tentando iniciar esse serviço mas tenho erro de acesso negado, mesmo que eu já tenha permitido o acesso pelo regedit. Alguma idéia?

Comment: Tente executar `sfc /scannow` no prompt de comando, veja se resolve

Comment: Além disso, você está usando uma conta administradora?